# Create List from received object?

Tags: c#

i need to create a list from an object my class receive. But i can't do it?

```
[XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public class PackIt
{

    [XmlElement("pack")]
    public List<object> objects { get; set; }

    public PackIt(object model)
    {
         objects = new List<model.GetType()>();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `PackIt` generic:

```
[XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public class PackIt<T>
{

    [XmlElement("pack")]
    public List<T> objects { get; set; }

    public PackIt()
    {
         objects = new List<T>();
    }

}

PachIt<string> packIt = new PackIt<string>();
```